# Grand total with cart price rule

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have a cart price rule for free shopping.

the problem is there is no grand total in the cart price rule.

if I use subtotal then if the customer uses a 50% off discount then the free shopping will apply because the customer reaches the subtotal.

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is Grand Total includes Shipping: Grand Total = SubTotal + Ship + Tax + ... (many other things such as discount)

So check your logic again.

Comment: you are right. but what about subtotal + discount ( in cart price rule )

Comment: It is in the setting `Apply to Shipping Amount` https://i.imgur.com/lb6Rvql.jpg